# Error: Attempted to call method isEmpty on null context

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this html/thymleaf template that has been working with the th:if statements. The code uses the if statements to only show the div, and it's contents, if there is something in that field in the SQL database.

I am trying to add a new Private String cyberAttackInsurance and use the same code to display it but it is throwing this error: Method call: Attempted to call method isEmpty() on null context object

Why is this a problem on this bit of code and not on the rest of the code? I tried writing it differently with using a th:block and th:switch th:case, but it didn't like that either... that threw a different error. Any ideas how to fix this error or more insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code with the cyberAttackInsurance added.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="fragments/layout" th:with="currentPage='dashboard'">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div  class="container" layout:fragment="content">
<div class="row">
    <br/>

    <div class="ui segment">
        <div class="ui container">
            <div th:if="${param.sentMessageFail}">
                <div class="ui warning message">
                    <p style="color: #ffffff; text-align:left;"> Oops! Something went wrong. Please try submitting your form again.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.sentMessage}">
            <div class="ui positive message">
                <p style="color: #ffffff; text-align:left;"> Sent Successfully!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col m6 xl3 valign-wrapper">
            <div th:if="${access!=null and !access.micrositeLink.isEmpty()}" class="card xs scale-transition scale-out z-depth-0">
                <a th:href="${access.micrositeLink}" target="_blank">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="images/ReferralMicrosite.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Submit a new opportunity</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col m6 xl3 valign-wrapper">
            <div th:if="${access!=null and !access.partnerPortalLink.isEmpty()}" class="card xs scale-transition scale-out z-depth-0">
                <a th:href="${access.partnerPortalLink}" target="_blank" style="background-color:#2f373e;color:white;">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="images/ProspectManager.png"/>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Track all your referral business</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col m6 xl3 valign-wrapper">
            <div  th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')} or ${loggedUser.client.ams360Affiliate == 'All Access – Traditional'}" class="card xs scale-transition scale-out z-depth-0">
                <a href="https://platform.vertafore.com/#/" target="_blank">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <img src="images/ams360.png"/></div>
                </a>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Agency Management System</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col m6 xl3 valign-wrapper">
            <div  th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')} or ${loggedUser.client.ams360Affiliate == 'All Access – Traditional'}" class="card xs scale-transition scale-out z-depth-0">
                <a href="https://rating.vertafore.com/UserInterface/main/login.aspx" target="_blank">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="images/plRating.png"/>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Personal Lines Comparative Rater &amp; Quoting</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex" style="margin-bottom:0;">
        <div class="col s12 xl6">
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:-5px;">
                <div class="col s6 m4 scale-transition scale-out">
                    <a th:href="@{/carriers}">
                        <div class="white red-text text-accent-2 valign-wrapper ">
                        <span class="center-align" style="width:100%; padding:10px;">
                            <img src="/images/menu_icons/icons8-handshake-48.png"/>
                            <br/>
                            <span class="grey-text text-darken-2">Know your carriers!</span>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${access!=null and !access.indioCustomerApplicationSite.isEmpty()}" class="col s6 m4 scale-transition scale-out">
                    <a th:href="${access.indioCustomerApplicationSite}" target="_blank">
                        <div class="white text-accent-4 valign-wrapper ">
                             <span class="center-align" style="width:100%; padding:10px;">
                                 <img class="responsive-img" src="images/Indio.png"/>
                                <br/>
                                 <span class="grey-text text-darken-2">Online Applications for your customers to complete</span>
                             </span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col s6 m4 scale-transition scale-out">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.university.com/">
                        <div class="white valign-wrapper ">
                        <span class="center-align" style="width:100%; padding:10px;">
                            <img src="/images/menu_icons/icons8-reading-48.png"/>
                            <br/>
                            <span class="grey-text text-darken-2">University</span>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div th:if="${access!=null and !access.cyberAttackInsurance.isEmpty()}" class="col s6 m4 scale-transition scale-out">
                    <a th:href="${access.cyberAttackInsurance}" target="_blank">
                        <div class="white valign-wrapper ">
                        <span class="center-align" style="width:100%; padding:10px;">
                                 <img class="responsive-img" src="images/vendor_logos/CAI.jpg"/>
                            <br/>
                            <span class="grey-text text-darken-2">Cyber Attack Insurance</span>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${access!=null and !access.hiscoxQuotingSite.isEmpty()}" class="col s6 m4 scale-transition scale-out">
                    <a th:href="${access.hiscoxQuotingSite}" target="_blank">
                        <div class="white black-text text-accent-4 valign-wrapper ">
                             <span class="center-align" style="width:100%; padding:10px;">
                                 <img class="responsive-img" src="images/vendor_logos/hiscox_logo.gif"/>
                                <br/>
                                 <span class="grey-text text-darken-2">Online Quoting site for <strong>P&amp;C licensed Affiliates only</strong></span>
                             </span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${access!=null and !access.CRQLink.isEmpty()}"  class="col s6 m4 scale-transition scale-out">
                    <a th:href="https://esubmissions.thehartford.com/" target="_blank">
                        <div class="white black-text valign-wrapper " >
                                    <span class="center-align" style="width:100%; padding:10px;">
                                        <img class="responsive-img" src="images/hartford-logo.png"/>
                                        <br/>
                                        <span class="grey-text text-darken-2">The Hartford Pocket </span>
                                    </span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${access!=null and !access.hartfordCustomerQuotingSite.isEmpty()}" class="col s6 m4 scale-transition scale-out">
                    <a th:href="${'mailto:?body=Thank you for your interest in our Commercial Lines Insurance, here is a link to get a quote online NOW! '+access.hartfordCustomerQuotingSite+'&amp;subject=Thank you for your interest!'}" >
                        <div class="white black-text valign-wrapper" >
                                    <span class="center-align" style="width:100%; padding:10px;">
                                        <i class="material-icons center-align" style="font-size:3.25rem">mail_outline</i>
                                        <br/>
                                        <span class="grey-text text-darken-2">Email: Link to Hartford Customer Facing Rater </span>
                                    </span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 xl6">
            <div class="white scale-transition scale-out" style="padding:5px 10px">
                <h6><Strong>Latest Announcements</Strong></h6>
                <table class="table striped" data-toggle="table" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="3">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                         <tr th:each="announcement : ${announcements}">
                                <td>
                                    <a th:href="@{|/announcement/${announcement.id}|}">
                                    <h6><strong th:text="${announcement.heading}">Announcement Heading</strong></h6>
                                        <small class="designation" th:text="${announcement.description}">Description for this announcement.</small></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="center-align">
                                    <h6><strong th:if="${announcement.createdDate}" th:text="${#dates.day(announcement.createdDate)}">28</strong></h6>
                                    <h6><strong th:if="${announcement.createdDate}" th:text="${#dates.monthName(announcement.createdDate)}">Feb</strong></h6>
                                </td>
                         </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="white scale-transition scale-out " style="padding:5px 10px">
                <h6 style="margin-bottom:-40px;"><strong>Resources Directory</strong></h6>
                <table class="table striped highlight" data-toggle="table" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="4">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Services</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="resource : ${resources}">
                        <td><a th:href="@{/}" th:text="${resource.name}"></a></td>
                        <td th:text="${resource.category}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${resource.services}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.scale-out').addClass("scale-in");
        });
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the model:

```html
@Entity
public class ResourceWebsiteAccess {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ResourceWebsiteAccessId")
    private Long id;
    private String micrositeLink;
    private String partnerPortalLink;
    private String hartfordCustomerQuotingSite;
    private String hiscoxQuotingSite;
    private String indioCustomerApplicationSite;
    private String CRQLink;
    private String cyberAttackInsurance;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client")
    private Client client;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMicrositeLink() {
        return micrositeLink;
    }

    public void setMicrositeLink(String micrositeLink) {
        this.micrositeLink = micrositeLink;
    }

    public String getPartnerPortalLink() {
        return partnerPortalLink;
    }

    public void setPartnerPortalLink(String partnerPortalLink) {
        this.partnerPortalLink = partnerPortalLink;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getHartfordCustomerQuotingSite() {
        return hartfordCustomerQuotingSite;
    }

    public void setHartfordCustomerQuotingSite(String hartfordCustomerQuotingSite) {
        this.hartfordCustomerQuotingSite = hartfordCustomerQuotingSite;
    }

    public String getHiscoxQuotingSite() {
        return hiscoxQuotingSite;
    }

    public void setHiscoxQuotingSite(String hiscoxQuotingSite) {
        this.hiscoxQuotingSite = hiscoxQuotingSite;
    }

    public String getIndioCustomerApplicationSite() {
        return indioCustomerApplicationSite;
    }

    public void setIndioCustomerApplicationSite(String indioCustomerApplicationSite) {
        this.indioCustomerApplicationSite = indioCustomerApplicationSite;
    }

    public String getCRQLink() {
        return CRQLink;
    }

    public void setCRQLink(String CRQLink) {
        this.CRQLink = CRQLink;
    }

    public String getCyberAttackInsurance() {
        return cyberAttackInsurance;
    }

    public void setCyberAttackInsurance(String cyberAttackInsurance) {
        this.cyberAttackInsurance = cyberAttackInsurance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if `cyberAttackInsurance` is null first like you're doing it for `access`

```
<div th:if="${access!=null and access.cyberAttackInsurance != null and  !access.cyberAttackInsurance.isEmpty()}" class="col s6 m4 scale-transition scale-out">
```

Even better you can simply use conditional operator

```
<div th:if="${access?.cyberAttackInsurance}" class="col...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgot to set the `cyberAttackInsurance` ? The error is because you're calling `isEmpty()` but it is `null` and hence why you are seeing a null pointer here.

Comment: I want the page to load whether or not there is a value in the cyberAttackInsurance. I just don't want the div/box with the cyberAttackInsurance info to show to a user that doesn't have a value in the cyberAttackInsurance field.

Comment: In that case you need to add a check that it isn’t null before you call `isEmpty()`